# Between or among?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Should I use *between* or *among* in the sentence?

You must choose between/among the three books.

Comment: I'd use *among* (more than two), but there's some support for using *between* these days. See [definitions 4 & 5](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/between), for example, and contrast them with definitions 1-3.

Comment: You would only use "between" for a relatively small number of options, and only for the case where a single option is to be selected.

Comment: I'd say *from among.*

Comment: @Hot Licks, would choosing "from among" a list also imply that only a single option is to be selected?  I believe so.

Comment: @thomj1332 - "From among" does not (strongly) imply whether a single choice or multiple choices is expected.

Comment: Just for fun, look up the etymology of each word. Be- tween: *of two* / Among: *in mingling*

Answer (score 0):

I would say, "You must choose ***one of*** the three books."

You could also say "...*from among* the three books." as suggested in the comments, but the two ways of saying it mean different things.  It depends on if you want to say that only one book can be chosen?  Or, do you want to leave room for the person to choose 2 or 3 books out of the 3?  "...from among the three books." gives room for this.

Answer (score -1):

Choose "among" more than two items, and "between" just two.  The following is outright wrong: "The flying stone hit him squarely among his eyes."

I'll extend this fun topic to discuss one of my real pet peeves, as illustrated in the following example:
*You must choose one of the following actions: (a) to fly a kite, or (b) to take a hike.*

The above example illustrates an ubiquitous error in that "*or*" is incorrect; it should be "*and*".  This is a very common error, even in legal documents.

Comment: As written, *or* is fine for your kite/hike example.

Comment: @Lawrence I think so too, A:"You must choose blue **or** yellow", B: "You must choose between blue **and** yellow", *You must choose one of the following...* is equivalent to  A

Comment: So the following sentence is grammatically incorrect? *"If I had to choose a colour between blue, yellow and green, I'd go for blue"*